# tabView in PrimeFaces 5.0 doesn't call tabChange event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, onchange, tabview

I use PrimeFaces 5.0 and jsf 2.2. Here is my page that contains PrimeFaces tabview

```
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:100%;">
            <p:tabView id="tabs" activeIndex="#{TabsManagerBean.activeIndex}" onTabShow="$('#tvlistr').click();" dynamic="true"
                value="#{TabsManagerBean.tabs}" var="tab">
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{TabsManagerBean.onTabChange}" />
                <p:tab title="#{tab}" titleStyle="width:180px" />
            </p:tabView>
            <p:commandLink id="tvlistr" style="display:none;" action="#{TabsManagerBean.navigate}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

My onTabChange method

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent evt) {
    logger.debug("Tab changed to: {}.", evt.getData());
    selectedTab = (String) evt.getData();
    ...
}
```

and the problem that this method isn't called. i need this method to be called before

```
<p:commandLink id="tvlistr" style="display:none;" action="#{TabsManagerBean.navigate}"/>
```

Updated: here is my h:form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view locale="en">
    <h:head>
        <title>#{appMsg.common_pms}</title>
        <!--  main JavaScript file -->
        <h:outputScript name="js/main.js" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="formId" prependId="false">

            <ui:include src="progressbar.xhtml" />

            <h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block" style="position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;height:90px;">
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="position:absolute;top:60px;width:100%;">
                <p:tabView id="tabs" activeIndex="#{TabsManagerBean.activeIndex}" onTabShow="$('#tvlistr').click();" dynamic="true"
                    value="#{TabsManagerBean.tabs}" var="tab">
                    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{TabsManagerBean.onTabChange}" />
                    <p:tab title="#{tab}" titleStyle="width:180px" />
                </p:tabView>
                <h:commandLink id="tvlistr" style="display:none;" action="#{TabsManagerBean.navigate}">
                    <f:ajax event="action" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup id="footer" layout="block" style="position:absolute;height:20px;width:100%;bottom:0;background-color: #005696">
                <ui:include src="/templates/version.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Comment: Can you show us h:form?

Comment: Is `TabsManagerBean.activeIndex` called or are you able to call `TabsManagerBean.navigate` through the command link?

Comment: @Smutje, `TabsManagerBean.activeIndex` is called and `TabsManagerBean.navigate` is also called only `TabsManagerBean.onTabChange` is not called

Comment: Have you checked for any errormessages using the p:message tag, or any js errors on the page?

Comment: @EmilKaminski, there is no error, i just need to get into `onTabChange` method

Comment: @slavov - Try changing the argument type of `onTabChange` to `AjaxBehaviorEvent` and set `cache="false"`. This feels like a bug

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Primefaces 5.1

As long as i put the tabview into a form everything worked fine.
But because i wanted to use seperate forms in my tabs i had to remove the surrounding form of the tabview to avoid nested forms. 
Without the surrounding form the ajax event didn´t get triggered any more when changing the tab.

My solution was to use a remotecommand in a form parallel to the tabview.
The remotecommand is triggered by the onTabChange attribute of the tabview element.
At that call i forwarded the index parameter to the global request parameters.

```
<p:tabView id="rootTabMenu" styleClass="tabcontainer" prependId="false" 
        activeIndex="#{sessionData.activeTabIndex}" widgetVar="rootTabMenu"
        onTabChange="tabChangeHelper([{name: 'activeIndex', value: index}])">
    // Tabs...  
</p:tabView>

<h:form id="tabChangeHelperForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="tabChangeHelper" actionListener="#{sessionData.onTabChange()}" />
</h:form>
```

In the backing bean i catched the value again from the request parameter map and set the active index.

```
public void onTabChange()
{   
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String paramIndex = paramMap.get("activeIndex");
    setActiveTabIndex(Integer.valueOf(paramIndex));
    System.out.println("Active index changed to " + activeTabIndex);
}
```

Hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug related to dynamically built tabs. Removing the "var" and "value" and presenting static tags will cause the listener to fire properly. Might want to file a bug report.

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" activeIndex="#{TabsManagerBean.activeIndex}" onTabShow="$('#tvlistr').click();" dynamic="true">            
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{TabsManagerBean.onTabChange}" />
         <p:tab title="First tab" titleStyle="width:180px" />
         <p:tab title="Second tab" titleStyle="width:180px" />
 </p:tabView>
```